# Text to Yaml list in python

Tags: python, parsing, text, yaml

I am trying to learn python on my own and am trying to dump content of a textfile.txt to a yamlfile.yaml in the following manner:

Textfile.txt content:

Rosie
Emma
Julie
Jack
Kate

Yamlfile should have:

name: Rosie
group: 121\Rosie
name: Emma
group: 121\Emma
name: Julie
group: 121\Julie

What I have done so far is:

```
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml
a= '121\'
in_file = Path(Testfile.txt)
out_file= in_file.with_suffix('.yaml')
data = {}
index = 0
for line in in_file.open()
   line= line.strip()
   index=+1
   data= dict(name=line, group= '%s %s' % (a, line)) 
yaml.dump(data, out_file)
```

The output shows only info on Rosie. I think the problem lies with   data= dict(name=line, group= '%s %s' % (a, line)).
Really appreciate any pointer.
Thanks!

Comment: Your example is missing some needed quotations marks, please ensure you include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that others can test your code w/o seeing any syntax errors

Comment: But yes, the problem is in your `dict` line, you are creating a new dictionary every time through the for loop and overwriting the `data` variable with the latest.  You will need to append each dictionary to a list or other data structure which you initialize outside the loop and append to each time through the loop.  Then yaml.dump that instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please review data structure for "data", i think list fit here, and append the list.

```
from pathlib import Path
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

a = "121\\"
yaml=YAML() # pls add yaml object 
in_file = Path("Textfile.txt")
out_file= in_file.with_suffix('.yaml')
#data = {}
data=[] # list would be better data structure here
index = 0
for line in in_file.open():
    line= line.strip()
    print(line)
    index=+1
    #data= dict(name=line, group= '%s %s' % (a, line)) --> assigning the value, so basically overwriting
    data.append(dict(name=line, group= '%s %s' % (a, line)) ) # you would need to append
print(data)
yaml.dump(data, out_file)
```

Comment: It worked!!Thank you. I am looking into data now :)